# Axis DMsuite RESTful API

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm looking at Axis DMsuite for masking Oracle databases.  I was told by their staff that they exposed some simple REST endpoints for triggering masking jobs, but I have done a fair bit of searching and found no documentation.  Is anyone familiar?

Specifically, I want to know if the API allows triggering a masking job against a specified database

Something like this would be awesome:

```
POST 10.80.123.45/dmsuite_api/jobs/123/start
BODY DATA [sid=mydb&user=SYSTEM&password=yaywoohcool]
```

Comment: Have you found out anything since?

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan Nope, sorry!  Are you trying to do something similar?

Comment: Yeah. Actually I spoke to someone from Axis and they explained to me that the jobs/dddddd/start API is the only API that they offer. Are  you using this with Delphix?

Comment: Great!  That's fine, as long as I know then.  Toss that up as an answer and I'll accept it.  A job is tightly coupled with an "environment", so you can't change databases, correct?

Comment: Yeah the job is linked to a database beforehand. I'm thinking of writing some casperjs /phantomjs scripts to automate db/environment setup on demand. It's one of our requirements here.